# How to separate the application bar buttons for each PanaramaItem in the Windowsphone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I have totally two PanaramaItems in my PanaramaPage of my windows phone application. I need to show two ApplicationBarItems in the first Panrama item and 3 Application Bar items in the second PanaramaItem.. Is there any to do this Xaml page... I don't want to do anything through code behind... Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure in this case you'll have to programmatically manipulate the toolbar for each PanoramaItem.  If you don't want to do it in code behind and are using a mvvm framework there are ways to do it without coupling the ViewModel to the View.  You could create a service that both items could access to manipulate the toolbar.  In Caliburn Micro each VM has a reference to the View and manipulation could be done that way.  Further in CM an IResult can be created and fired off in the OnActivate for each item.